# How to get id from dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a list:

```
public IList<SelectListItem> ToCountryList { get; set; }
```

I have this line in the razor view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Filter.ToCountryId, Model.ToCountryList, string.Empty, new { style = "min-width: 100px; width:180px" })
```

Now I want jQuery to select `ToCountryId` from the selected value of the dropdownlist.
I need the id of the record. For example - I have a pair: ID-NAME 5-USA. So I need to retrieve 5 (int)

How should I get the id?

This gives nothing:

```
$("select[name='Filter.ToCountryId'] option:selected").val()
```

HTML from browser (not sure how to publish - so plain text):

```
..select starts

select id="Filter_ToCountryId" name="Filter.ToCountryId" style="min-width: 100px; width:180px"

option tags with countries

..select ends
```

Comment: Could you publish the piece of the generated html ?

Answer (score 3):

Just give your dropdown a deterministic id:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.Filter.ToCountryId, 
    Model.ToCountryList, 
    string.Empty, 
    new { id = "myddl", style = "min-width: 100px; width:180px" }
)
```

and then you could easily get the selected value using an id selector:

```
$('#myddl').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take value from the select itself, not from the option:

```
$("select[name='Filter.ToCountryId']").val()
```